# Drawer Indicator on ActionBar compat v7 21

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-compat, drawertoggle

My application uses `ActionBarCompat` library as well as the `NavigationDrawer` support library.
I use `ActionBarDrawerToggle` appcompat v7 to get the drawer. There are a custom search view on `ActionBar`. Like this:

[image]

But the drawer indicator shows wrongly, doesn't show the Back Arrow when action search view is expanded;
[image]

I want it to show like PlayStore application:

[image]

How can I do it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got that issue because you set `(android:)homeAsUpIndicator` in your theme. Remove that attribute will solve your problem.

Answer (score 3):

There is simple and quick solution to this.

First, you should know now the android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle is deprecated.
You must replace that with android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle.

Here is an Example showing the same.

```html
DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
        this,  mDrawerLayout, mToolbar,
        R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close
    );
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
```

After that use support Action Bar as shown [here in this documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/setting-up.html#ApiLevel7) and then your drawer indicator will show correctly also showing the Back Arrow when action search view is expanded.

Remember to use com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.+" (Api level 21)
 and android.support.v7.app.ActionBar

You can set up the support library using this [guide](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html).

AND after that your drawer indicator will perfectly look like this..!!!

[image: AND then your drawer indicator will perfectly look like this.]

Comment: Please read my question carefully. Anyway, the question was resolved. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the arrow from `ActionBarDrawerToggle`. I think Google uses `Toolbar` as they do in google io app. On OnClick event they just change toolbar navigation icon with `toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.id.ic_up)`. And `R.id.ic_up` - is a custom arrow drawable.

Comment: I tried it. You don't need to call `toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.id.ic_up)`. It happens by default.

Comment: Its weird because if u use new AppCompat lib and theme, ActionBar is actually Toolbar

Answer (score 0):

For me none of solutions posted here in SO worked. I had to look under the hood of support library to find out why and when is the home icon set and I noticed few things. The main observation is that the icon is set in this function:

```
android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar#setNavigationIcon(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)
```

on the line

```
 mNavButtonView.setImageDrawable(icon);
```

If you are facing the same problem as I was and none of suggested solutions work (setting theme, trying to call setNavigationIcon on toolbar, setHomeAsUpIndicator on Actionbar or even something else), I suggest to locate function mentioned above and put breakpoint there. You can then see when the function is called and identify the last function call (from the Frame window in android studio) that sets up the icon. For me it was this activity life-cycle method syncing navigation drawer:

```
@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    mToolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_hamburger);
}
```

I simply added last line and it worked.